# Whats a good use case for an EIMI?

Tags: c#, .net, interface

EIMI being an explicit interface member implementation. So instead of:

```
public int SomeValue{get;}
```

you have

```
int SomeInterface.SomeValue {get;}
```

I'm currently considering using one as i'm using an internal interface (to decouple, yet restrict) and I don't want to make the methods on the implementing object to appear in its public API.

Is this a good use case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, that's a good use case. According to [C# Language Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664591(VS.71).aspx) on MSDN:

> Explicit interface member implementations serve two primary purposes:
>
> - Because explicit interface member implementations are not accessible through class or struct instances, they allow interface implementations to be excluded from the public interface of a class or struct. This is particularly useful when a class or struct implements an internal interface that is of no interest to a consumer of that class or struct.
> - Explicit interface member implementations allow disambiguation of interface members with the same signature. Without explicit interface member implementations it would be impossible for a class or struct to have different implementations of interface members with the same signature and return type, as would it be impossible for a class or struct to have any implementation at all of interface members with the same signature but with different return types.

Comment: Explicit interface member implementations are not accessible through class or struct instances. +1 At the same time implicit interface member implementations must be always public.

Answer (score 8):

A very good example is in the .Net generic collections classes.

For example, `List<T>` implements 'IList' implicitly and `IList` (non generic interface) explicitly. That means when you use the class directly you'll only see the specialized methods and not the ones that work with Object.

Let's say you instantiate a `List<Person>`. If IList was implemented implicitly you'd have two add methods directly accessible on the class  Add(Person item) and Add(Object item), which will break type safety provided by generics. Calling list.Add("Foo") will compile just fine as the Add(Object) overload will get chosen automatically, and type safety provided by generics is gone.

Answer (score 2):

From book CLR via C# you can find other reason of using EIMI: types safety and boxing avoid

For example, you have implement IComparable interface:

```
struct SomeValueType1 : IComparable
{
    private int _v;

    public SomeValueType1(int v)
    {
        _v = v;
    }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        return _v - ((SomeValueType1)obj)._v;
    }
}
```

Look into implementation of method CompareTo:
Is not type safe. As parameter it get object. If type of object will not SomeValueType1 - it will crash in run-time

Using:

```
SomeValueType1 svt1 = new SomeValueType1(0);
Object o1 = new Object();
Int32 res = svt1.CompareTo(svt1);
res = svt1.CompareTo(o1);
```

Third line do boxing from svt1 into Object. 4-th line will generate run time error

Lets use EIMI:

```
struct SomeValueType2 : IComparable
{
    private int _v;

    public SomeValueType2(int v)
    {
        _v = v;
    }

    public int CompareTo(SomeValueType2 svt2)
    {
        return _v - svt2._v;
    }

    int IComparable.CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        return CompareTo((SomeValueType2)obj);
    }
}
```

Using:

```
SomeValueType2 svt2 = new SomeValueType2(0);
Object o2 = new Object();
res = svt2.CompareTo(svt2);
res = svt2.CompareTo(o2);
```

Third line do not do boxing! 4-th line will generate compile time error

As Jeffrey Richter wrote in CLR via C# 4-th edition: "This discussion clearly shows you that EIMIs should be used with great care. When many developers first learn about EIMIs, they think that they’re cool and they start using them whenever possible. Don’t do this! EIMIs are useful in some circumstances, but you should avoid them whenever possible because they make using a type much
more difficult."

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I would like to clarify what "disambiguation of interface members" means by example (Vojislav Stojkovic, the 2nd example):

```
public interface IWindow {
   Object GetMenu();
}

public interface IRestaurant {
    Object GetMenu();
}
```

Two different interfaces have methods with the same name and signatre. But we want to implement both interfaces:

```
public sealed class MarioPizzeria : IWindow, IRestaurant  {
    //Explicit inteface member implementation for IWindow      
    Object IWindow.GetMenu();

    //Explicit inteface member implementation for IRestaurant
    Object IRestaurant.GetMenu();

    //An optional method that has nothing to do with an interface
    public Object GetMenu(); 
}
```

Usage:

```
MarioPizzeria mp = new MarioPizzeria();
mp.GetMenu(); //MarioPizzeria's public method

//IWindow.GetMenu method
IWindow window = mp;
window.GetMenu();

//IRestaurant.GetMenu method
IRestaurant restaurant = mp;
restaurant.GetMenu();
```

An interesting [fact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664591(VS.71).aspx):

- Explicit interface member implementations are not accessible through
  class or struct instances.
- Implicit interface member implementations must be always public.